# Joomla writes timezone JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT to database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

I am now researing for a couple of hours and can not get any solution...
on my local webserver everything works fine.
But on the live server it does not work.
The website is 1:1 the same.

**My Problem is:** if a user is logged in and wants to edit his profile, he will get a dropdownlist of all the timezones, so he can select his preferred timezone. The default select item should be blank but instead there is as follow:

`<option value="JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT">- Use Default -</option>`

on my local server is looks as follow:

`<option value=>- Use Default -</option>`

The problem with that is, that it will store `JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT` into my database on the live server (on my local server it works perfectly). When you will go back to yoour profile, Joomla wants to convert `JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT` back to a timezone, which of course does not exist... so I will get an error page.

I saw that there is no default timezone set on the live server in the php.ini, but I do not have access to the php.ini file, so I tried with a .htaccess solution, which di not make any difference: `php_value date.timezone "Europe/Zurich"`.

Comment: Please post your 2nd question as a standalone question, as they don't seem related to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your profile.xml / frontend.xml file. (I did not understand where you are editing).

Option value should be "" and not JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT.

`<option value="">JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT</option>`

Also on your local server

`<option value=>- Use Default -</option>`

this is NOT a valid syntax for HTML.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, maybe here I was not 100% clear... this is a copy past from my browser, when I did "Inspect Element" on the drop down element. the strange thing is, that the frontend.xml is looking correct e.g. <option value="">JOPTION_USE_DEFAULT</option>

Comment: Still it's not valid. Check in the code if you changed something.

Comment: yes sorry see my edit.. it saved my comment before I was done writing